# LiveUSB operational issues

Tags: ubuntu, liveusb

I'm running UNETBOOTIN on my USB stick. Ubuntu 10.04.02 is running OK, but I have two usability questions:

**1)** Is there a way to enlarge the *persistent storage* now that I've found need for more than 100MB originally allocated?

**2)** How do I *mount* the actual "Windows" side of the stick? I can't seem to find something specific in mount:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mount | sort
aufs on / type aufs (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/dev/sda1 on /media/SYSTEM type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
/dev/sda2 on /media/OS type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/ubuntu/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

Gnome's Places menu only lists SYSTEM (mostly the r/w Casper filesystem portion of the LiveUSB stick) and OS (my local Windows hard drive). Both are visible as fuseblock /sda devices, so there's nothing to un-hide.

Comment: The question contains two independent questions. It would be good idea to make separate question for each of them. In that case it would be possible to improve the title as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the first part:
**It's a good idea to backup the image first.**

Add 500MB of zeroes to the end of the image casper-rw. Make sure you use >> (append) and not > (overwrite).

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=500 >> casper-rw
```

Resize the filesystem to cover the entire image file

```
resize2fs casper-rw
```

That should be it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, I agree with bbaja42's answer. If you have space on the stick, consider adding more than 500 MB; it fills up faster than you might think.

Second part:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat
```

This is the stick's main partition, despite the name of the mount point.